# how to select from two table in sql in a special case?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a problem in my query to select from two table in a case like that
**savanh** table that hold student data and add_class table that hold foreign key of savanh that is savanh_id, now i want to select just those student form savanh table that not added in add_class table yet.
below query not work please any idea?

```
SELECT  savanh.savanh_id,asass_number, name, father_name, grand_father
FROM savanh, add_class
WHERE savanh.savanh_id != add_class.savanh_id;
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS`. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu can for example use a LEFT JOIN:
A left join will give you the data in savanh as base data. Then the data of add_class is matched against that.

All records which can not be matched, are the ones we want to keep, which gives you your WHERE clause with the NULL check.

```
SELECT savanh.savanh_id,asass_number, name, father_name, grand_father 
FROM savanh
LEFT JOIN add_class ON savanh.savanh_id = add_class.savanh_id
WHERE add_class.savanh_id IS NULL;
```